# create table in power bi that contains newly added funds from base table

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I need to create one virtual table in power bi which contains only newly added fund names (means funds which are only present in the current year and not present in any of the previous year. below is the sample data which contains old and new fund names.

Sample data:

[image: Sample data]

Answer (score 0):

The first DAX-expression will return a table that is filtered to rows where the Fund Names do not ocurre in previous years:

```
Table_previous_Year_Fundnames = 
VAR previous_Year_Fundnames =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Fund Name] ),
        YEAR ( 'Table'[Report date] ) <> YEAR ( TODAY () )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE ( 'Table', NOT 'Table'[Fund Name] IN previous_Year_Fundnames )
```

For the new Fund Names only, you need to use just this part:

```
previous_Year_Fundnames =
        CALCULATETABLE (
            VALUES ( 'Table'[Fund Name] ),
            YEAR ( 'Table'[Report date] ) <> YEAR ( TODAY () )
        )
```